# .NET Core 2.2 time.ToString("d", culture) Exception

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a very strange situation, mydatetime.ToString("d", culture) sometimes throws exceptions.

This is simple Azure Premium function V2 running in Azure on .Net Core 2.2. It is a trigger on storage queue. This trigger processes ~2.5mil times a month. Sometimes the ToString throws 'External component has thrown an exception';

```
try {
 var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(order.Address.Country.CultureCode);

 var date = order.CreatedDate;

 var test = date.ToString("d", culture); //This throws exceptions.
} catch (Exception exception) {
 await StaticLoggers.HandleExceptionAsync(new BaseServices.Models.ExceptionModel {
  Environment = "CustomException",
   Message = $ "{order.CreatedDate.MyToDateString()} {order.Address.Country.CultureCode} " + exception.Message.MyToStringTrim(),
   StackTrace = exception.StackTrace.MyToStringTrim()
 });

 return null;
}
```

From logs, the exceptions are completely random, sometimes there's a day without errors, sometimes there's ~1000. What I have observed is that it does throw more during high peak times, so I my best guess is that this has something to do with parallel execution in Azure. Also, the date and culture vary when the exceptions show up, so I also suspect that this is not the cause of the error.
This is a message I log when ToString throws exception.

```
2020/01/10 01:10:24 de-DE External component has thrown an exception.
```

Date is never null, and real cultures are always present. If I comment the ToString line, the errors don't occur.

Stack trace:

```
at Interop.Kernel32.EnumCalendarInfoExEx(EnumCalendarInfoProcExEx pCalInfoEnumProcExEx, String lpLocaleName, UInt32 Calendar, String lpReserved, UInt32 CalType, Void* lParam) 
at System.Globalization.CalendarData.GetCalendars(String localeName, Boolean useUserOverride, CalendarId[] calendars) at System.Globalization.CultureData.get_CalendarIds() 
at System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.set_Calendar(Calendar value) 
at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.get_DateTimeFormat() at System.DateTimeFormat.Format(DateTime dateTime, String format, IFormatProvider provider, TimeSpan offset) 
at System.DateTimeFormat.Format(DateTime dateTime, String format, IFormatProvider provider) 
at Automation.ProcessOrderEvent.EventService.EventWorkflowService.GetOrderAsync(Int32 orderId) in C:\...\EventService\OrderUpdated.cs:line 328
```

Update 1:
The error message above is the full stack trace, nothing has been removed or edited except the physical path for security reasons.
This is the boiler plate on top level.

```
using BusinessLogicLayer.Services;
using BusinessLogicLayer.Services.Interfaces;

[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace Automation.ProcessOrderEvent
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IOrderService, OrderService>();
        }
    }

    public class ProcessOrderEvent
    {
        private readonly IOrderService _orderService;

        public ProcessOrderEvent(IOrderService orderService) => _orderService = orderService;

        [FunctionName("ProcessAwesomeEvent")]
        public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("eventqueue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] string myQueueItem, ExecutionContext context, ILogger logger)
        {
            await _orderService.ProcessOrderUpdate(myQueueItem);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code in order service:

```
public partial class EventWorkflowService
{
    public async Task ProcessOrderUpdate(orderId)
    {
        var order = await GetOrderAsync(orderId);
        if (order == null)
            return;

        var date = order.CreatedDate.ToString("d", new CultureInfo(order.Address.Country.CultureCode));
        //rest of the code
    }
}
```

The GetOrder is a simple A System.Data.SqlClient query that gets data and binds them to the order model.

Comment: Hi Edward, may I know how did you get the "order"(I want to check the code above the try catch code you provided) ? And could you please the whole error message ?

Comment: The error message above is the full stack trace, nothing has been removed or edited except the physical path for security reasons. I also updated the post with more code.

Comment: The top frame in that stack trace has nothing to do with your code, so this seems like a bug in .NET Core 2.2 - I would file it at https://github.com/dotnet/corefx

Comment: It's not yet solved, I have my own solution which I'm testing. I'll update the post if it works.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, we can find a line of:

```
at System.DateTimeFormat.Format(DateTime dateTime, String format, IFormatProvider provider)
```

**But "DateTimeFormat" just exists in "System.Globalization.CultureInfo" in .net 2.2**.

And another line in your error message is:

```
at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.get_DateTimeFormat() at System.DateTimeFormat.Format(DateTime dateTime, String format, IFormatProvider provider, TimeSpan offset)
```

So I think it may cause the error message, these two "DateTimeFormat" don't match.

As I can't see all of your code and function, so I can just provide this information which I suspect maybe the reason for your reference. Please check your code and pay attention to the "DateTimeFormat" in your code(Maybe when you get the order from sql, I guess the "DateTimeFormat" was "System.DateTimeFormat" when you get it from sql, and when you new "CultureInfo", if can just use "System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat" in .net 2.2).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by upgrading the solution to .NET Core 3.1 and Azure functions to V3 from .NET Core 2.2 and Functions V2.
I haven't seen the bug occur anymore since the upgrade, so my best guess is that it was ether .NET Core 2.2 or Azure function V2 bug.